# Angular1: Pinch to Zoom functionality

Tags: angularjs

I tried many libraries/solutions including `ionic-scroll` but it doesn't work out. I need something which is much similar to instagram/facebook zoom functionality on mobile view.

Every solution prevents vertical scroll if user want to move to second image under the first one.

I am using Angular 1 in my app.

Can someone suggest me so that I can implement the same?

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Comment: @Neel no solution so far